# Problems with mbstring in Ubuntu 17.10 upgrade

Tags: php, 17.10, phpmyadmin

Today, after upgrading from my Ubuntu to 17.10 the sites in my localhost and *PhpMyAdmin* have stopped working. The cause was `mbstring`. When I try to run *PhpMyAdmin* I get the warning: `The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.`

When I run: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring`
I get: `Package "php7.0-mbstring" has no installation candidate.`

My PHP Version: *7.0.24-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1*

Tks

Comment: How did you install php ? The php version looks old "ubuntu16.04.1" ? mbstring is in universe - https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/php-mbstring

Comment: I installed PHP 7, Apache 2 and MySql manually shortly after installing Ubuntu 16.04 a few months ago. I recently upgraded Ubuntu to 17.04 and still everything worked fine, even today when I upgrade to 17.10. The mbstring that is in the universe is for PHP version 7.1, my version is 7.0 that I can not upgrade to 7.1 because some of my applications do not support it.

Comment: You should probably update your question with that information. It is a little late now, but in the future when you upgrade I would check version compatibility with php and what not. php is a bit complex, you can try installing the php-mbsrting from an older version of ubuntu (download the .deb and install with dpkg -i , then put the php packages on hold). If that fails you may need to compile from source, I am not sure.

Comment: In artful, the package is `sudo apt install php7.1-mbstring`

Answer (score 0):

As I was in a hurry to solve the problem, I decided to start from scratch: I removed PHP 7.0 and tried reinstal, but ...

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

Installed version 7.1 again !

Well, I decided to follow its orientation and compiled version 7.0, but ... again problems arose and again I could not install`mbstring`.

Without further delay, I had to decline and install version 7.1 in order to continue developing my work. My problem now is just Magento, which in the version I use does not accept 7.1.

I'll see it coolly later: either I do a dowgrade of Ubuntu or upgrade the version of Magento ... Anyway, thank you [Panter](https://askubuntu.com/users/35795/panther) and others for attention.